# date format in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdateformatter

I want to ask that how i get the device date and time format in my like device setting am/pm or 24 hrs what time and what format is set???
Like if i use this format

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"mm-dd-yyyy"];
insertCmd = [insertCmd stringByAppendingString:formatter setDateFormat:@"MM.dd.yyyy"];
```

it set the date format but i want the setting user set in device?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSLog(@"date = %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

This is for converting current date to string. It should be based on the `currentLocale` of the device. You dont have to set anything. However I am not sure what you meant by the code in your question.

This is what mentioned in [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFDateFormatterRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kCFDateFormatterShortStyle),

> The format for these date and time styles is not exact because they
>   depend on the locale, user preference settings, and the operating
>   system version. Do not use these constants if you want an exact
>   format, for example if you are parsing an external data file which
>   contains date information in a fixed format. There are several
>   different “lengths” of the formats:

Comment: actually i want to set of date picker according to device date and time setting

Comment: If the question is about picker, you should post a new question. This is the answer for current question. Picker is different from what you have asked.

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setFormat:@"mm-dd-yyyy"];
NSString* dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
insertCmd = [insertCmd stringByAppendingString:dateString];
```